# How to change jquery ui autocomplete source based on dropdown selection

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am a beginner using jQuery AutoComplete in a search box on my Index page:

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#searchName').autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("GetUsers", "Home")'
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="searchbox" style="float:left;">@Html.TextBox("searchName", null, new { @placeholder = "Name" })
```

Controller:

```
      public JsonResult GetUsers(string term)
  {
      Context db = new Context();
      List<string> users;
   .
   .
   .
      return Json(users, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

Right now, the Autocomplete is working, but my question is how can I hookup a drop-down that changes the source of the autocomplete to a different function, where a different set of users is searched?

In other words, I need the source of the Autocomplete function to change based on the value selected from a drop-down.

Is this possible?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a function for the source option: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Using this approach, you would update the javascript so that you have more control of the GET call so you can pass in a second parameter:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#searchName').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
           jQuery.get('@Url.Action("GetUsers", "Home")', {
               term: request.term,
               otherId: $('#otherDdl').val()
           }, function (data) {
               response(data);
           });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Then on the server you can check the passed in `otherId` and based on that change the source.

```
  public JsonResult GetUsers(string term, int otherId)
  {
      Context db = new Context();
      List<string> users;

      if(otherId == ???)
      // Default search
      else
      // Search alternate location

     .
     .
     .
      return Json(users, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

Comment: term is the string that is entered in the text-box correct?  Shouldn't the conditional be on the value from the drop-down?  I see what you are saying, but how do I inject the value from the drop-down into that if statement?

Comment: Updated my response to include the Select List. In my example, the name of the select list is 'otherDdl'

Comment: Okay, one more thing.  What about the ddl in the View?  Do I need to do anything special with that?

Comment: No, you would populate the ddl as you normally would and then when a user types something in '#searchName' the autocomplete would read the ddl selected value to include it with the get request.

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete `source` accepts a callback function use that to build your data based on dropdown value e.g. :

```
    if(dropdown.val() == 1){
       // hard-coded - get from external source
       var data = [{ "label": "test1", "value": "test1" },
               { "label": "test2", "value": "test2" },
               { "label": "test3", "value": "test3" } ];
    } else{
         ....
    }
```

Then in the autocomplete source assign it to response:

```
source: function (request, response) {
  response(data);                                        
},
```